# How to identify browser window opened by selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have manually opened one browser window for google.com and there is another browser window which is opened by selenium webdriver for google.com.

How do I identify which one is opened by selenium?

This question was asked to me in one interview. I answered that window opened by selenium will have no plugins and another was is to use driver.close but interviewer said that there is some other way also to identify.

Comment: It's usually is the one without any plugin. Why do you need to know that?

Comment: Close Selenium window by driver.close() and you will know which one is other window :-)

Comment: You could perform pretty much any action on the driver. Maximize it, close it, navigate to a website.

Answer (score 0):

I have observed that the window opened by Selenium has a robot icon near the URL. Whereas the one opened manually will have only the lock sign near the URL.